# Animate only pressed button

Tags: flutter

```
Wrap(
  children: dayOfWeek.map((day) {
    final isContain = widget.selected.contains(day['value']);

    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        _animationController.forward();
        widget.onDayClick(day['value']);
      },
      child: AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: _colorTween,
        builder: (BuildContext context, child) => Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: spacing(.5)),
          child: Chip(
            onDeleted: () => widget.onDayClick(day['value']),
            deleteIconColor: Colors.white,
            label: Text(day['label'], overflow: TextOverflow.clip),
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
              side: BorderSide(
                width: isContain ? 0 : 1,
                color: getTheme(context).dividerColor,
              ),
            ),
            backgroundColor: isContain ? kIndigo : _colorTween.value,
            labelStyle: TextStyle(
              color: isContain ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
            ),
            deleteIcon: Icon(EvaIcons.checkmark),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }).toList(),
),
```

I've tried using animation to animate background color for my chip widget. Every time it got clicked I want it to change color (indigo and gray).

There are 6 chips. Currently when I click one of them, all the other chips change to the same color.

How can I achieve only clicked chip color will be change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the same `controller` being used as other buttons'.

You can make the "**button/chip**" individually animated by making a standalone `StatefulWidget` of "**button/chip**" and make the `controller` and `isContain` (or make a variable for state) inside this new `Widget` instead.

Here's the example I've got, but using `TweenAnimationBuilder`. You can do the same technique as `controller` do.

The page:

```
class TestWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  createState() => _TestWidgetState();
}

class _TestWidgetState extends State<TestWidget> {
  @override
  build(context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      child: Container(
        padding:
            MediaQuery.of(context).padding.copyWith(left: 16.0, right: 16.0),
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: Column(
          children: List.generate(
            4,
            (index) {
              return CustomButton(
                child: Text('Button $index'),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The button:

```
class CustomButton extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;

  const CustomButton({Key key, this.child}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  createState() => _CustomButtonState();
}

class _CustomButtonState extends State<CustomButton> {
  bool isPressed = false;

  @override
  build(context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          isPressed = !isPressed;
        });
      },
      child: TweenAnimationBuilder(
        tween: isPressed
            ? ColorTween(
                begin: CupertinoColors.destructiveRed,
                end: CupertinoColors.systemYellow)
            : ColorTween(
                begin: CupertinoColors.systemYellow,
                end: CupertinoColors.destructiveRed),
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 600),
        builder: (_context, color, child) {
          return Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(
                color: CupertinoColors.inactiveGray,
              ),
              color: color, // This color is animated
            ),
            child: Center(child: child),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16.0),
          );
        },
        child: widget.child,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Preview :

[image: Custom Button Preview]

Answer (score 0):

I created custom chip using `ImplicitlyAnimatedWidget`, Check it [Demo](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/b81203486070c0b6d1f73b7fd7b24ccd)

```
class MyAnimatedChip extends ImplicitlyAnimatedWidget {
  final bool selected;
  final String text;
  final IconData iconData;
  final ValueChanged<bool> onPressed;

  MyAnimatedChip({
    this.selected,
    this.text,
    this.iconData,
    this.onPressed,
  })  : assert(text != null),
        super(
          curve: Curves.easeInOut,
          duration: const Duration(seconds: 1), //TODO: Change animation duration
        );

  @override
  _MyWid createState() => _MyWid();
}

class _MyWid extends AnimatedWidgetBaseState<MyAnimatedChip> {
  ColorTween _bgColorTween;
  ColorTween _contentColorTween;

  @override
  void forEachTween(TweenVisitor<dynamic> visitor) {
    _bgColorTween = visitor(
      _bgColorTween,
      _getBgColor(),
      (dynamic value) => ColorTween(begin: value),
    );

    _contentColorTween = visitor(
      _contentColorTween,
      _getContentColor(),
      (dynamic value) => ColorTween(begin: value),
    );
  }

  Color _getBgColor() {
    if (widget.selected == true) return Colors.indigo; //TODO: Change selected Color
    return Colors.grey;
  }

  Color _getContentColor() {
    if (widget.selected == true) return Colors.white;
    return Colors.black;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            widget.text,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: _contentColorTween.evaluate(animation),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(width: 5.0),
          Icon(
            widget.iconData,
            color: _contentColorTween.evaluate(animation),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      color: _bgColorTween.evaluate(animation),
      shape: StadiumBorder(
        side: BorderSide(
          color: Colors.red[200], //TODO: Change Border Color and width
          width: 2.0,
        ),
      ),
      onPressed: () => widget.onPressed(widget.selected),
    );
  }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final List<String> dayOfWeek = [
    "SunDay",
    "Monday",
    "TuesDay",
    "WednesDay",
    "ThursDay",
    "Friday",
    "SaturDay",
  ];

  final List<String> selectedDays = [
    "Monday",
    "WednesDay",
    "ThursDay",
  ];

  bool selectedX = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Initial Page")),
      body: Wrap(
        children: dayOfWeek.map((day) {
          return MyAnimatedChip(
            text: day,
            iconData: Icons.account_circle,
            selected: selectedDays.contains(day),
            onPressed: (selected) {
              setState(() {
                if (selected)
                  selectedDays.remove(day);
                else
                  selectedDays.add(day);
              });
            },
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Demo:** [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/b81203486070c0b6d1f73b7fd7b24ccd)

Answer (score 0):

Here i will provide an example using only **Implicit Animation**

we will wrap our button with **`AnimatedScale`**

```
class AnimatedAddButton extends StatefulWidget {
  const AnimatedAddButton({
    required this.onAddTapped,
    super.key,
  });

  final VoidCallback? onAddTapped;

  @override
  State<AnimatedAddButton> createState() => _AnimatedAddButtonState();
}

class _AnimatedAddButtonState extends State<AnimatedAddButton> {
  bool isClicked = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedScale(
      scale: isClicked ?  1.4 : 1,

      onEnd: () => setState(() => isClicked = false),
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
      child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            widget.onAddTapped?.call();
            setState(() {
              isClicked = true;
            });
          },
          child: Text( "Hit Me",)),
    );
  }
}
```

in the previous code i have used a normal **`ElevatedButton`**  with
**onAddTapped** function which is a Parameter passed to this widget
the Button is wrapped with **`AnimatedScale()`**
here i have also included a boolean flag called **`isClicked`** with default value of **false**

in the main **onPressed** i am calling the main **onAddTapped** function  via **`.call()`** method then i am setting new state of my own flag **isClicked**  to be **true**

my button is wrapped with an Animation widget that will smoothly animate a scale effect of my button according to the flag **isClicked**
it will be **x1.4** the  size and will do this animation in e.g **2 seconds**
I have also included and **onEnd** function inside the **`AnimatedScale`** to reset the flag again  via **setState(()=>);** to false after the end of the animation
so we can reuse the button again.

hope everything is clear.